# org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator;141) HHH000274: Unable to apply constraints on DDL

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, maven-3, weblogic11g

I am using JDK 1.7 with Maven 3.0 for my project.

When I have the following in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<version>6.0</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the following while deploying to Weblogic 10.3.6 integrated with Eclipse

```
WARN (org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator;141) HHH000274: 
Unable to apply constraints on DDL for test.entity.Employee
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:172)
```

If I remove `javaee-api` dependency, then I do have issues when I compile project using mvn compile with errors like

```
[ERROR] /domain/view/EmployeeNameConverter.java:[29,76] cannot access 
javax.el.ELContext
class file for javax.el.ELContext not found
[ERROR] /EmployeeNameConverter.java:[28,55] cannot access javax.el.ELResolver
class file for javax.el.ELResolver not found
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16603576/599528)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `javaee-api` are just the interfaces not the implementation. Seems you haven't answered your previous answer correctly.

Comment: @user714965 So how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Weblogic 11g doesn't support Java EE 6. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166283/weblogic-11g-and-javaee-6) for reference.

Comment: @user714965 Ah! well there is no EE5 right? Couldn't find for anything less than 6.0 [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api) Thanks

Comment: @user714965 I have used Java EE5 and that solved the issue. If you post an answer, I would be glad to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like we've worked out in the comments [Weblogic 11g doesn't support Java EE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166283/weblogic-11g-and-javaee-6). So one solution can be using Java EE5 instead.